# Text not changing even by using setState

Tags: flutter, dart, text

```
String title = '';
child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            final docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection('CIPsubmit')
                                .doc(wee)
                                .get()
                                .then(
                              (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                                final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                                final title = data['title'];
                                print(title.toString());
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
```

I am getting a string from firebase, and have put it in a setState to change a text value. The print shows that String title has updated to the right value, but the text is not changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**, *title* variable above *GestureDetector* is not the same with *title* inside that code

```
(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
     final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
     final title = data['title'];//with this. Instead you need to write below line code
     // title = data['title'];
     print(title.toString());
     },
```

**Secondly**, it seems very bad wrapping whole code in *onTap* with *setState*. You need to just wrap line, which you change title variable value.

```
setState((){
    title = data['title'];
});
```

**And finally**, a *title* variable(it is preferred declare all variables in State class out of build method) should be declared out of build method.

Comment: how are the title (s) not the same, they're literally the same spelling

Comment: @pika3113 there is more important things than just spelling. When you type final keyword you are just creating a new variable which is only visible inside that scope. For example you can create a function inside your state class and when you declare a variable named title and operate on it, operations will only affect that variable inside a function, not your class variable, despite their same name. Therefore I said that you have to remove final keyword inside scope. If you want that class variable(or variable inside build method in your case) must be final, then use `late final String title;`

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to put an asynchronous function, because the time when `setState` update the widget tree is NOT when the string is updated.
The fix is also simple:

```
                        onTap: ()  async /* NOTE: mark the anonymous function as asynchronous */ {
                            final docRef = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection('CIPsubmit')
                                .doc(wee)
                                .get();
                            final data = docRef.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                            final title = data['title'];
                            setState(() { print(title.toString();})
                            print(title.toString());
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        );
```

Comment: Theres an error: The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'.

Comment: Have you added the `await` keyword? `docRef` here shouldn't be a Future anymore. Anyway, the main idea is to move the asynchronous part out of `setState`.